# Initiate D3.js data map with new data

Tags: json, d3.js

I'm going with the basic example in [here](https://github.com/markmarkoh/datamaps/blob/master/README.md#custom-popup-on-hover) except I need to be able to update the map based on new data (a json file.) I couldn't find a way to load the data directly inside Datamap object, so I'm loading it with D3.json and using the command to update the map. For some reason the popupTemplate function is receiving null data object and I don't know how to fix it.

What's the best way to do this?

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://datamaps.github.io/scripts/topojson.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 500px; height: 300px;"></div>

<script>
    var data;

    var map = new Datamap({
        element: document.getElementById('container'),
        fills: {
            HIGH: '#afafaf',
            LOW: '#123456',
            MEDIUM: 'blue',
            UNKNOWN: '#FFFFFF',
            defaultFill: 'green'
        },
        geographyConfig: {
            popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
                console.log(data)
                return ['<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>',
                    'Number of things in ' + geo.properties.name,
                    ': ' + data[geo.id].numberOfThings,
                    '</strong></div>'].join('');
            }
        }
    });
    map.legend();


    d3.json("path/to/data.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) return console.warn(error);

        data = json;
        map.updateChoropleth(data);
    });
</script>
```

This is my json file:

```
{
    "IRL": {
        "fillKey": "LOW",
        "numberOfThings": "2002"
    },
    "USA": {
        "fillKey": "MEDIUM",
       "numberOfThings": "10381"
    }
}
```

To make it easier to debug, I put on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3yFT/1/)

Comment: Great.. you asked it here. thanks for the try. this might be helpful for me :).

Answer (score 1):

I did not have problems loading the data directly inside Datamap. In any case, I also simulated a data update...the color gets updated but not the value (numberOfThings). In the example in the tutorial, it is not clear this can be done although it would make sense that one should be able to update values.

I am leaving you with the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/r9bAL/) showing the results of my experiment.

A couple of notes:

- I believe your popup was not showing because its return string needs
  to be `data.numberOfThings`.
- If I am not mistaken when I played with this before, if you don't have data for a country, then the popup is not updated and the same value as for the last country with data is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

@Kiarash, there are two problems here:

1. You are using the Datamaps from the datamaps.github.io site, which I don't recommend since I can't guarantee reliability (uptime) or backwards compatibility. You are best off downloading it from the [Github project page](https://github.com/datamaps)
2. `data` won't have a property with the country name, it should be accessed like `data.numberOfThings`.

[Here is a working version of the code you supplied](http://jsbin.com/sehenomo/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: The problem is when JSON comes to play. I've tried similar to your code with JSON and it doesn't work. Could you please modify your with JSON? Also, I won't be using github links in my work, it's just for this example. Thanks!